Romans 9:22-23: What does "the objects of his wrath—prepared for destruction" precisely mean?
Romans 9:22-23

22 What if God, although choosing to show his wrath and make his power
known, bore with great patience the objects of his wrath—prepared for
destruction? 23 What if he did this to make the riches of his glory
known to the objects of his mercy, whom he prepared in advance for
glory

What does the objects of his wrath—prepared for destruction mean? does this project that God has favorites and he predestined some for glory and some for destruction before birth?
If not, what does this verse exactly means?

God's election is according to  His foreknowledge.

The phrase "objects of his wrath—prepared for destruction" (σκεύη ὀργῆς κατηρτισμένα εἰς ἀπώλειαν) in Romans 9:22 has sparked significant theological debate, particularly regarding predestination. To unpack its meaning, let's analyze it with reference to Jeremiah 27:25 (50:25 in English translations) and the broader biblical context.

Key Term: σκεύη ὀργῆς (Vessels of Wrath)
The term σκεύη ὀργῆς in both Romans 9:22 and Jeremiah 27:25 (LXX) refers to instruments or objects designated for a specific purpose within God’s sovereign plan. In Jeremiah 27:25, these "vessels of wrath" signify the Chaldeans (Babylonians), who act as God’s agents of judgment against Israel and other nations. These vessels are instruments used by God to fulfill a larger divine purpose, even though their actions are morally reprehensible.

Similarly, in Romans 9:22, the "objects of wrath" are individuals or groups who, through their persistent rebellion and sin, become vehicles of God’s justice. However, their role as "prepared for destruction" does not necessarily imply that God predestined them to damnation without consideration of their choices.


Prepared for Destruction: Active or Passive?
The phrase κατηρτισμένα εἰς ἀπώλειαν (prepared for destruction) is significant because the verb κατηρτισμένα is in the perfect passive participle. This suggests a state of being prepared, but it does not explicitly indicate who is performing the preparation.


Passive Preparation: This could imply that individuals, through their choices, have "prepared themselves" for destruction. In this view, their destruction is the natural outcome of their rebellion against God, aligning with biblical principles of human responsibility (e.g., Proverbs 16:4).

God’s Sovereign Role: Alternatively, some argue that God, in His sovereignty, permits individuals to become vessels of wrath, knowing their hearts and ultimate rejection of Him. This aligns with passages like Romans 1:24, where God "gives them over" to their sinful desires.




Does God Have Favorites?
Paul’s discussion in Romans 9 is deeply rooted in the context of God’s covenant faithfulness and His sovereign right to choose how He fulfills His purposes (e.g., choosing Isaac over Ishmael, Jacob over Esau). This does not imply arbitrary favoritism but rather emphasizes God's overarching plan to bring salvation to both Jews and Gentiles.

Romans 9:22-23 contrasts two types of vessels:

Vessels of Wrath: Those who persist in rebellion and ultimately face judgment.
Vessels of Mercy: Those who are recipients of God’s grace and are "prepared in advance for glory."

Importantly, Paul does not describe God creating vessels of wrath solely for destruction. Instead, he highlights God's patience, suggesting that He endures their rebellion to reveal His mercy and glory to others. This parallels Jeremiah 18:6, where the potter shapes clay, allowing for change depending on the clay’s response.


How Jeremiah 27:25 Illuminates Romans 9:22
In Jeremiah 27:25, the "vessels of wrath" (Chaldeans) were not inherently predestined for their role. Rather, God used their pre-existing evil tendencies to accomplish His purposes. This suggests that God’s sovereignty operates in tandem with human free will.

Paul’s use of the term in Romans 9 emphasizes that God’s actions always serve His greater redemptive purposes. The vessels of wrath highlight His justice, while the vessels of mercy display His glory and grace.


Does Romans 9:22-23 Teach Double Predestination?
The text does not explicitly teach that God predestines some individuals to destruction in the same way He predestines others to glory. Instead:


The vessels of wrath are tolerated with great patience, implying that God gives them ample opportunity to repent (see Romans 2:4).
The preparation of the vessels of mercy is described as God’s active work ("whom He prepared in advance for glory"), contrasting with the ambiguous preparation of the vessels of wrath.

This suggests that God’s ultimate desire is mercy, as seen in Romans 11:32, where Paul declares that God has bound everyone over to disobedience so that He may have mercy on all.
Conclusion
The "objects of his wrath—prepared for destruction" in Romans 9:22 do not necessarily mean that God predestines individuals to destruction without regard for their actions. Instead, the phrase emphasizes God's sovereign right to use even the rebellious for His purposes, demonstrating both His justice and mercy. The inclusion of Jeremiah 27:25 supports the interpretation that these vessels serve a role within God's plan but are not arbitrarily chosen for wrath.

Your comment best answer my question so far. I will wait for more answers before selecting one as I am interested in more discussions about this super controversial (at least for me) verse.

This verse is a challenging one so we must tread carefully to not say anything that the scripture does not say.

Or does the potter not have a right over the clay, to make from the
same lump one object for honorable use, and another for common use?
What if God, although willing to demonstrate His wrath and to make His
power known, endured with great patience objects of wrath prepared for
destruction? And He did so to make known the riches of His glory upon
objects of mercy, which He prepared beforehand for glory (Romans
9:21-23)


What we see is a distinction made between "objects of wrath" and "objects of mercy." Objects of mercy are clearly people prepared by God for glory. This implies that the "objects of wrath" are human beings who face judgment.
To support this, we see Paul refer to believers as formerly being "by nature children of wrath" (Ephesians 2:3). The lesson is that God's wrath is directed toward people who live in disobedience.

Whoever believes in the Son has eternal life; whoever does not obey
the Son shall not see life, but the wrath of God remains on him. (John 3:36)

God desires us to be moldable: (Isaiah 64:8)
But now, O Lord, you are our Father;
    we are the clay, and you are our potter;
    we are all the work of your hand. 

We might extend the metaphor. Hardened vessels are those who have become solidified in their rebellion and sin. God has the sovereign right to shape and mold us, and humans have the responsibility to remain responsive and pliable to His will.
Everyone has a need for God’s righteousness (Romans 1-3). God provided righteousness for humanity by grace through faith in Jesus Christ. (Ephesians 2:8-9)
God’s right to choose:

"If God has the right to choose who will be blessed and how, then some
might question whether God is unjust by not ensuring the same outcome
for everyone. Paul addresses this question in Romans 9:14–18,
explaining that God has the right (as the Creator) to have mercy on
whom He will have mercy and the right to harden whom He will harden
(Romans 9:18)." (GotQuestions)

Double election:

"Some have wrestled with Paul’s statement that there are vessels of
wrath prepared for destruction. Some have even concluded that he is
teaching a doctrine often called double election—that God chooses who
will not be saved in the same way He chooses who will be saved. But,
like Paul said in 1 Corinthians 4:6, we should not go beyond what is
written. We need to be careful about making inferences when a verse is
not explicit." (GotQuestions)

Hypothetical question:
Notice that Paul asked a question. He's not making a statement. This means that Paul could be proposing a possibility rather than stating doctrine.

"Paul raises a hypothetical—a “what if”—to remind readers that God has
the right to make such choices if He so desires. But Paul stops short
of asserting that God is making such choices. Paul’s point is that God
has the right to have mercy on whom He chooses and harden whom He
chooses (Romans 9:18), but that is different from asserting that God
chooses some not to be saved." (GotQuestions)


I don't see GotQuestions as a substantial reference myself. The  answers are anonymous, I believe.

@NigelJ Thank you for the feedback! When I have time I may update my answer. GotQuestions is anonymous. People must compare the answers with Scripture, not based on who wrote them. In this case I believe the quotations to be well substantiated. Regardless, perhaps I can find more substantial quotations!

Thank you @Jason_

@Jason_ Got Questions has 9,602 articles published and available on their web site. They also answer individual questions sent in to them by people from all over the world. Although I am a volunteer writer for them, I do not agree with everything they believe.  The views expressed in the articles you quoted from are backed up by Scripture. Individuals must use their own discernment and check against the Bible. This link explains more about them: https://www.gotquestions.org/about.html

So from what you wrote, I understand that indeed God has favorites ie he decides who he likes (will bless) and who he doesn't (set for destruction)?

@ccot That’s a good question. The Bible certainly teaches that God is sovereign and has the right to make choices according to His will and purposes. I would not describe this as having "favorites". I think that might be misleading. God’s decisions are not arbitrary. They are rooted in His very nature. His sovereignty, justice, love, and His desire for all to come to repentance rather than something as arbitrary as favoritism.

The key to understanding the “vessels of wrath” text in Romans 9 is to understand the entire book as an argument for the inclusion of the Gentiles in God’s plan of redemption. To a first century Jew, the Gentiles were unclean and were not fit to be in God’s presence (Acts 10:28).
In Romans 1, Paul identifies the entire world as God’s possession, including the Gentiles, but God gives them up to their sin. The first century Jews would have viewed themselves as part of the nation of Israel, chosen by God, and set apart from the rest of the nations.
“ The Lord your God has chosen you to be a people for his treasured possession, out of all the peoples who are on the face of the earth.” (Deuteronomy 6:6)
“The Lord set his heart in love on your fathers and chose their offspring after them, you above all peoples.” (Deuteronomy 10:15)
With the Gentiles being unclean, and the law coming to the nation of Israel, the Jews may have viewed their election as bringing salvation to them through the law. In Romans 2, Paul asserts that that same law condemns them because they don’t follow it perfectly. In Romans 3, Paul writes that both Jews and Gentiles are justified by faith, and that this upholds the law. Romans 4 shows how Abraham was justified by faith before he had been circumcised. So it is not the Jewish law that justified him, but faith in Yahweh. Romans 5 begins by describing how faith in Christ gives believers hope even in suffering, because both Jews and Gentiles were lawbreakers and enemies of God when Christ died for them. Romans 6 is an argument to pursue righteousness even though grace is found apart from the Jewish law, and Romans 7 is a defense of the law’s holiness and man’s inability. Finally, Romans 8 describes how both Jews and Gentiles are children of God if they have the “law of the Spirit of life” in Christ.
So we see that all of Romans up to this point has been about the inclusion of the Gentiles in the covenant promises through faith.
Finally, in Romans 9 Paul begins by lamenting that the majority of Jews have rejected Christ, since they (not the Gentiles) are the chosen people of God.
“They are Israelites, and to them belong the adoption, the glory, the covenants, the giving of the law, the worship, and the promises. To them belong the patriarchs, and from their race, according to the flesh, is the Christ, who is God over all, blessed forever. Amen.” (Romans 9:4–5)
Paul then addresses the question, if they were the elect, chosen people, did God’s plan fail? Are Gentiles plan B? His answer is no. Just like Esau was the firstborn, and the birthright, the blessings, and the promises were rightfully his, God had planned beforehand to bless Jacob. In this analogy, Esau is representative of the Jewish people, and Jacob is representative of the Gentiles—the illegitimate heir chosen/elected by God.
“As it is written, “Jacob I loved, but Esau I hated.” (Romans 9:13)
This is not about soteriology; it is a defense for the inclusion of the Gentiles. Just like the two sons in the story of the prodigal son in Luke 15, the elder son (representative of the Jews) was mad that the younger son (representative of the Gentiles) was forgiven. Now, Paul is explaining that God is not unjust for forgiving the Gentiles and for choosing the illegitimate heir to be his children.
“For he says to Moses, “I will have mercy on whom I have mercy, and I will have compassion on whom I have compassion.” So then it depends not on human will or exertion, but on God, who has mercy.” (Romans 9:15–16)
God shows compassion on His enemies, the Gentiles. He makes them his children. This is His mercy, and not their works.
The next example Paul gives is of Pharaoh, a Gentile and enemy of God.
“For the Scripture says to Pharaoh, “For this very purpose I have raised you up, that I might show my power in you, and that my name might be proclaimed in all the earth.” (Romans 9:17)
God chose/elected Pharaoh for his purposes and then hardened his heart. In the same way, God chose/elected the Jews and then hardened their hearts.
“So then he has mercy on whomever he wills, and he hardens whomever he wills.” (Romans 9:18)
He had mercy on the Gentiles and hardened the Jews just like he hardened Pharaoh’s heart. To the Jews who might reply, “it’s not fair, we’ve been faithful for generations, keeping the law and carefully recording our genealogies,” Paul writes,
“who are you, O man, to answer back to God?” Has the potter no right over the clay, to make out of the same lump one vessel for honorable use and another for dishonorable use? What if God, desiring to show his wrath and to make known his power, has endured with much patience vessels of wrath prepared for destruction, in order to make known the riches of his glory for vessels of mercy, which he has prepared beforehand for glory—even us whom he has called, not from the Jews only but also from the Gentiles?” (Romans 9:20-24)
The vessels of wrath (Gentiles) have been revealed as vessels of mercy, prepared beforehand for glory. The vessels of glory (those God has called) are not only the Jews, but also the Gentiles.
As indeed he says in Hosea,
“Those who were not my people I will call ‘my people,’
and her who was not beloved I will call ‘beloved.’ ”
“And in the very place where it was said to them, ‘You are not my people,’
there they will be called ‘sons of the living God.’ “ (Romans 9:25–26)
With this in perspective, the rest of the chapter speaks for itself. It’s all about the hardening of the Jews and inclusion of the Gentiles.
Romans 9:27–33 (ESV): And Isaiah cries out concerning Israel: “Though the number of the sons of Israel be as the sand of the sea, only a remnant of them will be saved, 28 for the Lord will carry out his sentence upon the earth fully and without delay.” 29 And as Isaiah predicted,
“If the Lord of hosts had not left us offspring,
we would have been like Sodom
and become like Gomorrah.”
Israel’s Unbelief
30 What shall we say, then? That Gentiles who did not pursue righteousness have attained it, that is, a righteousness that is by faith; 31 but that Israel who pursued a law that would lead to righteousness did not succeed in reaching that law. 32 Why? Because they did not pursue it by faith, but as if it were based on works. They have stumbled over the stumbling stone, 33 as it is written,
“Behold, I am laying in Zion a stone of stumbling, and a rock of offense;
and whoever believes in him will not be put to shame.”

Welcome to the site, Niles. The O.P. asked for a precise meaning, and you certainly gave one! You may already have checked out how this site operates, but in case not, you could go to https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour    https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803    https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq

"And the Lord said to her, "Two nations are in your womb, and two peoples from within you shall be divided; the one shall be stronger than the other, the older shall serve the younger."   Jacob becomes the nation of Israel and Esau becomes the nation of Edom.  This answer switches this around, which thing I have never heard before.  Can you edit in something to demonstrate Esau representing Israel a little more strongly since, everywhere else in Scripture, Esau is not Israel?

@Niles Excellent answer. +1

@Mike Borden You are confusing the physical pictures with their spiritual fulfilment. The real Israel are the believing Jews and gentiles gathered around the Messiah.

22For it has been written that Abraham had two sons, one of the slave woman and one of the free.
23But indeed, the one of the slave woman has been born according to flesh, but the one of the free, through the promise,
24which things are allegorized, for these are two covenants: one indeed from Mount Sinai, begetting unto slavery, which is Hagar.
25Now Hagar is Mount Sinai in Arabia and corresponds to the present Jerusalem, for she is in slavery with her children.
26But the Jerusalem above is free, who is our mother.

In Galatians 4, Paul calls the unbelieving Jews the Ishmaelites and the believers, regardless of their ethnicity, the promised descendents of Abraham.

9Behold, I give those from the synagogue of Satan—those declaring themselves to be Jews, and are not, but they lie—behold, I will cause them that they will come and will worship before your feet, and they shall know that I have loved you.

In Revelation 3:9 John switches around Isiah 43:4, 45:14 & 60:14.

@ארקדיוס I still think the primary allegorical distinction is between children born after the flesh (Ishmael, Esau) and children born after the spirit (Isaac, Jacob).  See Galatians 4:28-31.

Some translations speak of "objects of wrath" or "objects of mercy". Others, like the K.J.V. speak of "vessels of wrath" and "vessels of mercy". To speak of people as "vessels" rather than as "objects" is true to the way God looks upon humanity, as from the dust of the ground. The imagery of the potter taking clay (from the ground) to mold it into vessels for purposes of his choosing, is wonderfully used in the Bible to teach us many things, including here in Romans chapter 9.
This is where the verses preceding the one in question help answer the question. From verse 11 Paul begins to explain matters from God's point of view and illustrations from the past are used. Before the twins, Esau and Jacob, had been born, God had determined that the older would serve the younger, but "neither having done any good or any bad" - this was God's sovereign right as Creator to decide. God elected to have the older serve the younger, and that is what happened. God calls forth, and it happens. God decrees, and it is done.
Paul then asks if God's loving Jacob and hating Esau makes God unrighteous (v. 14). Absolutely not, and the example of how God dealt with Pharaoh is then given. God "raised [him] up, that I might shew my power in thee, and that my name might be declared throughout all the earth" (v.17).
This leads to the condemnation of those who, having been made by God, question how he has made them, finding fault with God, and resisting his will (as did Pharaoh - and see what happened to him.)
And the next bit is the verse in question - God endures with much long-suffering those vessels of wrath fitted to destruction. This is to "make known the riches of his glory on the vessels of mercy, which he had afore prepared unto glory," both Jews and Gentiles.
In light of the context, what does "the vessels of wrath fitted to destruction" actually mean? As the question puts it, "Does this project that God has favorites and he predestined some for glory and some for destruction before birth?" God certainly favours some, to lead them to glory (Jacob, before he was even born). God certainly does not favour others, who will be smashed, as like a potter taking a cracked, filthy vessel and hurling it to the ground (Pharaoh - who God certainly knew all about, before he was born.) The verse means exactly what it says.
But human ideas about favouritism spoil this whole section in Romans chapter 9. We think of how we are drawn to some, and how we dislike others; of how we show favouritism in many walks of life, due to our feelings, and despite not knowing things about people that would change our minds about showing partiality to them. God knows everything about everybody, long before they are even born. So, he tolerates with great long-suffering, many who rage against him and who do not want to do his will. Yet his mercy is there, to be granted to all who would acknowledge that they only deserve his wrath, but who put faith in his provision to be forgiven. Then will "vessels of clay" be cleansed, made fit for containing the riches of his glory from above.
God does not immediately smash human vessels that are unclean, for we are all unclean, and even "our righteous acts are as filthy rags" (Isaiah 64:6) which Paul quotes in Romans 3:10-12. To understand the argument Paul builds up, the need is to start at the first verse in Romans and to keep reading right through to the verse in question. Then it should become clear.
To conclude, here is what Paul says about the matter from God's point of view:

"But we are sure that the judgment of God is according to truth
against them which commit such things... Or despiseth thou the riches
of his goodness and forebearance and longsuffering; not knowing that
the goodness of God leadeth thee to repentance? ...[God] will render to every man according to his deeds: to them who by patient
continuance in well doing seek for glory and honour and immortality,
eternal life: but unto them that are contentious, and do not obey the
truth, but obey unrighteousness, indignation and wrath, tribulation
and anguish, upon every soul of man that doeth evil of the Jew first,
and also of the Gentile. But glory, honour, and peace, to every man
that worketh good, to the Jew first, and also to the Gentile. For
there is no respect of persons with God." Romans 2:4-11 K.J.V. (Bold
emphasis mine.)


"God certainly does not favour others, who will be smashed, as like a potter taking a cracked, filthy vessel and hurling it to the ground". Doesn't that contradict the loving God (in Christianity) who died on the cross for our salvation? if some will be smashed why he created them to start with?

@ccot  Salvation due to what Jesus did will be the blessing for all who humbly agree with God's righteous judgment - that all sinners must be punished, but that putting faith in what Jesus did to be punished in our stead gives a free pardon. God patiently waits, not forcing anyone into repentance. But if they don't accept that the law that is against us was taken out of the way by it being nailed to the cross (Col. 2:14), then the law will remain (in their case), God will judge them by it, and their condemnation will eventually come. No lack of love or justice on God's part.
